# Neo4j: why the performance of allShortestPaths function is so slow?

Tags: performance, neo4j, query-optimization, cypher, slowdown

I am using Neo4j 'neo4j-community-2.3.0-RC1' version.
In my database there are just 1054 nodes.
when i do path query with 'allShotestPaths' function, why it is so slow.
it take about more than 1 second,the following is unit test result :

```
  √ search optimalPath Path (192ms)
  √ search optimal Path by Lat Lng (1131ms)
```

should i optimize the query? the following are querys for 'optimalPath' and 'optimal Path by Lat Lng'

optimalPath query:

```
MATCH path=allShortestPaths((start:潍坊_STATION )-[rels*..50]->(end:潍坊_STATION {name:"火车站"}))
RETURN NODES(path) AS stations,relationships(path) AS path,length(path) AS stop_count, 
length(FILTER(index IN RANGE(1, length(rels)-1) WHERE (rels[index]).bus <> (rels[index - 1]).bus)) AS transfer_count, 
length(FILTER( rel IN rels WHERE type(rel)="WALK"  )) AS walk_count
order by transfer_count,walk_count,stop_count
```

optimal Path by Lat Lng query:

```
MATCH path=allShortestPaths((start:潍坊_STATION {name:"公交总公司"})-[rels*..50]->(end:潍坊_STATION {name:"火车站"}))
 WHERE
round(
6378.137 *1000*2*
asin(sqrt(
     sin((radians(start.lat)-radians(36.714))/2)^2+cos(radians(start.lat))*cos(radians(36.714))*
     sin((radians(start.lng)-radians(119.1268))/2)^2
 ))
)/1000 < 0.5      // this formula is used to calculate the distance between two GEO  coordinate (latitude\longitude)
RETURN NODES(path) AS stations,relationships(path) AS path,length(path) AS stop_count, 
length(FILTER(index IN RANGE(1, length(rels)-1) WHERE (rels[index]).bus <> (rels[index - 1]).bus)) AS transfer_count, 
length(FILTER( rel IN rels WHERE type(rel)="WALK"  )) AS walk_count
order by transfer_count,walk_count,stop_count
```

you can download the database here:https://www.dropbox.com/s/zamkyh2aaw3voe6/data.rar?dl=0

i will be very grateful ,if anybody can help me. thanks

Comment: Your uploaded database misses most store-files.

Comment: Have you seen the haversin function? http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-functions-mathematical.html#functions-haversin

Comment: what are the {lat} and {lon} parameters you pass in?

Comment: sorry , it is a parameter, i changed it with the real value

Comment: i upload the database again https://www.dropbox.com/s/zamkyh2aaw3voe6/data.rar?dl=0   , i upload the whole 'data' folder, please check, thanks a lot

Comment: I just tested it with 2.3.0 the queries run both in a few (10) milliseconds in the neo4j-shell, see: https://gist.github.com/jexp/573f36d83e04c930a9aa

Comment: sorry , At the top of the query , i have to remove {name:"公交总公司"}, it will be MATCH (start:潍坊_STATION ) WHERE .............., then the query will take more than 1 second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, without knowing more, I would pull the predicates and expressions that can be computed before the paths are all expanded, before the match.

And as your geo-filter is independent of anything else except your parameters and the start-node you can do:

```
MATCH (start:潍坊_STATION {name:"公交总公司"})

WHERE 
// this formula is used to calculate the distance between two GEO  coordinate (latitude\longitude)
round(6378.137 *1000*2* 
      asin(sqrt(sin((radians(start.lat)-radians({lat}))/2)^2
      +cos(radians(start.lat))*cos(radians({lat}))*
       sin((radians(start.lng)-radians({lng}))/2)^2)))/1000 
< 0.5      

MATCH (end:潍坊_STATION {name:"火车站"})
MATCH path=allShortestPaths((start)-[rels*..50]->(end))
RETURN NODES(path) AS stations,
       relationships(path) AS path,
       length(path) AS stop_count, 
       length(FILTER(index IN RANGE(1, length(rels)-1) 
             WHERE (rels[index]).bus <> (rels[index - 1]).bus)) AS transfer_count,
       length(FILTER( rel IN rels WHERE type(rel)="WALK"  )) AS walk_count

ORDER BY transfer_count,walk_count,stop_count;
```

see this test (but the other query is equally fast):

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ MATCH (start:潍坊_STATION {name:"公交总公司"})
> 
> WHERE 
> // this formula is used to calculate the distance between two GEO  coordinate (latitude\longitude)
> round(6378.137 *1000*2* 
>       asin(sqrt(sin((radians(start.lat)-radians({lat}))/2)^2
>       +cos(radians(start.lat))*cos(radians({lat}))*
>        sin((radians(start.lng)-radians({lng}))/2)^2)))/1000 
> < 0.5      
> 
> MATCH (end:潍坊_STATION {name:"火车站"})
> MATCH path=allShortestPaths((start)-[rels*..50]->(end))
> WITH NODES(path) AS stations,
>        relationships(path) AS path,
>        length(path) AS stop_count, 
>        length(FILTER(index IN RANGE(1, length(rels)-1) 
>              WHERE (rels[index]).bus <> (rels[index - 1]).bus)) AS transfer_count,
>        length(FILTER( rel IN rels WHERE type(rel)="WALK"  )) AS walk_count
> 
> ORDER BY transfer_count,walk_count,stop_count
> RETURN count(*);
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
| 320      |
+----------+
1 row
10 ms
```

Comment: i upload the database again dropbox.com/s/zamkyh2aaw3voe6/data.rar?dl=0 , i upload the whole 'data' folder, please check, thanks a lot

Comment: sorry , At the top of the query , i have to remove {name:"公交总公司"},   it will be MATCH (start:潍坊_STATION ) WHERE ..............,     then the query will take more than 1 second

Comment: i think, it is a hard problem. thanks a lot for your reply